# Bootstraping Percona Xtradb Cluster in Docker gives the error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, percona, xtradb

My goal is to get a Percona XtraDB Installation running in a Docker Container.
For this i wrote up the following configuration.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:wily
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
#
# ENVIRONMENT INSTALL
#
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y wget curl netcat python-dev python-setuptools python-software-properties vim
RUN easy_install j2cli
COPY my.cnf.j2 /templates/
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh /
#
# PERCONA XTRADB CLUSTER INSTALL
#
RUN echo "deb http://repo.percona.com/apt wily main" >>     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt wily main" >>     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y percona-xtradb-cluster-56
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -e
j2 /templates/my.cnf.j2 > /etc/mysql/my.cnf
exec bash
```

my.cnf.j2

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
max_allowed_packet=128M
binlog_format=ROW
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_node_address={{node_ip}}
wsrep_cluster_name="mycluster"
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
wsrep_node_name={{node_name}}
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth="test:test"

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm:// normally holds a list of 3 node WAN-IPs, i removed them due to privacy.

Building the image works perfectly fine with:

```
docker build --rm -t test .
```

Starting works also fine with:

```
docker run --name Test1 -e "node_ip=127.0.0.1" -e "node_name=Test1" -p 3306:3306 -p 4567:4567 -p 4444:4444 -p 4568:4568 -i -t test
```

The variable node_ip points at the WAN-IP of my server, i set it to 127.0.0.1 just for privacy reasons.

But when i try to bootstrap mysql in the container with:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql bootstrap-pxc
```

I get this error:

```
2016-03-28 09:24:09 354 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-03-28 09:24:09 354 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-03-28 09:24:09 354 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-03-28 09:24:09 354 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-03-28 09:24:09 354 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
160328 09:24:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/8605688929d8.pid ended
```

How can i solve this to get the XtraDB running in my Container?

Comment: afaict you're not running a mysql_install_db is there any reason for this ? (it would need to be run and then chown mysql.mysql -R /var/lib/mysql)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_install_db
chown mysql.mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start`

The above appears to work without issue, please test it out.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions problem. Try adding the following after your `FROM` statment:

```
RUN useradd mysql \
    && mkdir /var/lib/mysql \
    && chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: It sadly didn't help, i have still the same problem.